# How to let hibernate handle inheritance automatically?

Tags: hibernate, inheritance

I have B extends from A,and set InheritanceType to JOINED,the code like this:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "parent")
 public class Parent implements IsSerializable
 {
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<A> children;
        ...
 }


 @Entity
 @Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
 public class A implements IsSerializable
 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;
 }

 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
 public class B extends A
 {
     String name;
 }
```

then push a A to list

```
   A a=new A();
   list.getChildern().add(a);
```

push a B to list

```
   B b=new B();
   list.getChildern().add(b);
```

then

```
    Parent p=new Parent();
    p.setChildren(list);
    hibernate.persist(entity);
```

hope first element of the list will will be saved into table_A,and second element will be saved into table_B automatically.but they are not.What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your're not persisting `a` and `b`, so they're not made persistent. Either persist them explicitely, or add a cascade of type PERSIST to the `children` list, so that the persist operation is cascade from the perent to its children.

Comment: I added @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) to list,but same result as before

Comment: And what's the result? You told us what didn't happen, but you didn't tell us what happened. Any exception? What's the stack trace? What happens?

Comment: Sorry,the result is:tables for parent and A and join table got generated,and the data got saved,but no table got generated for B.